# Access database is being reset every time i build my C# project

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem that all the records in my Access database are being reset every single time I build and run the project from visual studio, But the records are not being reset when I run the program from the execution file, So the problem occurs after building the projects, And you know that any changes in the project need building to be executed, How can I fix this so when I build the project the records won't be removed from the Access database?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add more details. Like what query your program is running. If possible, post the complete code for others to review and try themselves. Do remember to remove sensitive and/or copyright content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build the project, VS recreates all files on the debug file and rewrites the access file too. So you should change the type of access file as a newer copy. Like this
[image: this]